# Run WebSocket Server locally

Tags: websocket

I'm creating application with SIP phone. I need setup WebSocket Server locally for tests. After searching in Internet I can't found easy to install and configure solution.

Can you recommend me WebSocket Server solution?

Comment: Operating system (linux, windows, etc...)? platform (.NET, Java, node.js),etc...?

Comment: @vtortola
system linux. Platform is irrelevant (as I think if I need ws:// address it's neutral with platform it will be used).

Answer (score 3):

Well, the question is way to open, since because WebSockets are just a type of transport, it is difficult to find a "easy to install and configure solution". You will need to choose a base framework, a websocket library and then cope with the particularities of such combination.

For example, you can use

- node.js and socket.io : https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener/wiki/Mono-support
- Mono and WebSocketListener : https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener/wiki/Mono-support
- Java and its WebSocket: https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2013/12/websockets-an-introduction/
- PHP/Apache and Ratchet: http://socketo.me/

Of, if you have already a TCP service, you can use WebSockify to provide the same service through WebSockets: https://github.com/kanaka/websockify

So it is a matter of taste and what you feel more comfortable with.